# can I use adb shell to send commands to my application

Tags: android, adb, xamarin.android

I want to find a way to create commands that I can send to my application using the adb shell or similar. This way I can do some small changes to my program without having to reload my application every time I change anything.

Is there a way to open the adb shell and send a command to a running application ?

If that is not possible, then what is a possible way to send commands to my application so I can do things like (Move the UI Elements) or (Create a file from a URL) or a number of other things.... Essentially I want to be able to send string commands to my application.....

If I can do that with the command line tools that would be sweet. otherwise What would be a good way to go about this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From an adb shell, type `am`. You can start activities and services as well as send broadcast intents. No arguments will print usage info.

From the host machine you can do `adb shell am <command>` if you want to invoke this from scripts.

Comment: Does this mean I have to make a provider to handle URI Requests ? or can I send arbitrary commands ?

Comment: if so. do you know of a good starting point for this solution ?

Comment: You can send any command that you can encode as an Intent. :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html explains how to handle broadcast intents.

Comment: I might add that you probably don't want to leave something like this in your app for release versions unless you want other things to be able to send the same commands to your app.

Comment: yes. Duly Noted. I am using this for developing. Since I am using monodroid I will probably put in a #if or something similar to exclude it when releasing.

Comment: From the Mono for Android side of things, the simplest way to handle sending commands to a running app is to use a BroadcastReceiver and have your BroadcastReceiver.OnReceive() method check the Intent for the command+arguments. You can even return data to the caller by using BroadcastReceiver.SetResult() or BroadcastReceiver.ResultData.

Comment: Excause me. I have used `adb shell am` to start an activity. The activity may have `Log.d()` for log something. But the log would not show on host machine's command prompt. How can I redirect the log to stdout? Actually, I just want the activity execution may have a result and let my shell script get it. I would like something like `VAR="$(adb shell am start <command> | grep result)"`.

Comment: OK I think I can get it from `adb logcat -d | grep ...`

Answer (score 4):

The `adb shell am` option is probably the cleanest/best/most awesome option, but you could have a Thread in your app checking for the presence of a specific file on the SD card. Something like (DON'T USE THIS CODE WITHOUT SERIOUS MODIFICATIONS):

```
public void run()
{
   File f = new File("/sdcard/appcommands");
   while(!stop){
      if(f.exists()){
         // read file
         // obey commands
         // remove file or use some other timing monitor
      }
   }
}
```

then you can just use `adb push` to write command files. Truly inefficient, but it can be made to work in a pinch. You can also do more complex things like creating local TCP/HTTP servers and using adb port forwarding, but that may just be overkill.

Comment: voted up for a creative quick solution. But i will likely accept the adb shell am as my solution. I just need to get more information on it.

Comment: Alternatively you can listen for broadcasts instead of `while(!stop)` and still push commands via `adb push`. This would allow to send more complex data to the app.