# send AT command using adb shell

Tags: android, modem, at-command

I need to send AT command to modem. I am using samsung galaxy S3 I9300 device, which is rooted.

The steps I did are:

```
abd shell
su
echo -e "AT\r"
```

But I am not sure how to read the response given by the above commands. I tried to redirect the command as follows:
`echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0`, but when I execute cat `/dev/smd0` I do not see any response I just see "AT". Seems like the command I intended to be executed is interpreted just as string and I see that string instead of the result of that operation.

Please advice what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855482/sending-at-commands-via-adb-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811828/can-i-use-adb-shell-to-send-commands-to-my-application

Comment: @Rajesh.. I guess, OP is talking about the AT Commands for the Phone Modem...

Comment: Or try this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286331/adb-shell-script-to-send-at-commands-to-a-modem-cannot-return-control-to-a-shell

Comment: It is the proper output.. Try putting some other commands like `ATD123456789;\r`

Comment: thanks for all the answer. However all the links you referred to I had already tried with no luck. I think my problem is that I am not identifying correct serial line to the modem and thus the AT commands I execute are not sent to the modem. But http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241 link doesn't explain how did it choose /dev/ttyGS0. Here is the result of cat /proc/tty/drivers on my device:

Comment: cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
rfcomm               /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
g_serial             /dev/ttyGS    251 0-3 serial
usbserial            /dev/ttyUSB   188 0-253 serial
s3c2410_serial       /dev/ttySAC   204 64-67 serial

Comment: After a bit more research it turn out that I do not need to go so much low level and identify the serial line to the modem. Instead I can use rild-debug.
            LocalSocket socket = new LocalSocket();
            LocalSocketAddress sockAddr = new LocalSocketAddress("rild-debug",
                    LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.RESERVED);
            socket.connect(sockAddr);

            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            String s = "ATD+37491472524\r";
            os.write(s.getBytes());
            socket.getOutputStream().close();

Comment: By this I was expecting to make a call to the specified number however I do not get any results. Nothing happens; neither errors nor results. Any idea?

Comment: its becuase you are not usin \n
try echo -c "AT\r\n" > /dev/smd0
this should work

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try out my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program which should be exactly what you are asking for: a program to send AT commands from the command line and capture the output.

In your case the result should be like

```
$ abd shell
$ su
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/smd0 -

OK
$
```

and to capture the output just put a file name instead of the last `-`.

Comment: How do I install your `atinout` program on my android device ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried that in **adb shell**

```
su

echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that interactively:

```
while read a;do echo -e "${a}\r" >>/dev/smd7 ; timeout 1s cat /dev/smd7;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
strace 2>/dev/null -e inject=ioctl:retval=0 microcom /dev/smd7
```

for an interactive session :D